# Azure Devops azure pipelines agents TCP connection failing

Tags: azure-devops

We are trying to start using the Azure Pipelines agents instead of Self hosted ones. While trying to convert over or Acceptance tests I am running into an issue with the agent not allowing our test to connect to an api we spin up with in the Agent that is running on port 44392. Noticed this post. [How to open TCP port on localhost on VSTS build agent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44652906/how-to-open-tcp-port-on-localhost-on-vsts-build-agent?rq=1), from a couple years ago and is pretty similar to how our test is working. Just wondering if the answer is still accurate or not.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to open TCP port on localhost on VSTS build agent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44652906/how-to-open-tcp-port-on-localhost-on-vsts-build-agent)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your are using the Hosted Agents, which means that the machine is a shared resource between many Azure DevOps Organizations (tenants) and managed (and locked) down by Microsoft.

In other words, we do not provide end user to open port with these agents. The answer in your link is still valid.

You may have to install an agent on your own virtual machine and run the build there. The VM can be in the cloud or on premise. You trade simplicity and cheapness for full control.